# Percentage profit/loss question

Tags: percentages

A shopkeeper sells a T.V. for 3000 and makes a profit of 15%. He sells a different T.V. and makes a loss of 10%. In the overall transaction, the shopkeeper makes neither profit nor loss. What is the cost price of the second T.V.?

I tried finding the cost of the first T.V. by dividing 3000 by 1.15 which is approximately 2609. It means that 15% is equal to 391. Since the shopkeeper neither gains or loses, 15% of the cost of the first T.V. should be equal to the 10% cost of the second T.V.. 10% of cost of second T.V. is equal to 391. Therefore the second T.V. costs 3910. However, the book says the answer is 3913. Have I done something wrong?

Also notice that 3000 divided by 115 is 26.086 and if we take just 26.08 the answer would have been 3920. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: You shouldn’t round your numbers before you get to the answer. Then you would get the same answer as the book.

Comment: but have I solved correctly?

Comment: Your method is correct. But Like I say, your issue is rounding your numbers too early.